# Crash when pressing Z or X

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried to use Z and X to adjust the ambientspeed while in game but when i press them it crashes completely im new to unity and c# so not sure what is wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float AmbientSpeed = 250.0f;

    public float RotationSpeed = 150.0f;

    private Rigidbody _rigidBody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        while (Input.GetKeyDown("z"))
        {
            AmbientSpeed = AmbientSpeed - 1;
            if (AmbientSpeed < 0)
            {
                AmbientSpeed = 0;
            }
        }

        while (Input.GetKeyDown("x"))
        {
            AmbientSpeed = AmbientSpeed + 1;
            if (AmbientSpeed > 250)
            {
                AmbientSpeed = 250;
            }
        }

        Debug.Log(AmbientSpeed);
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        UpdateFunction();
    }

    void UpdateFunction()
    {

        Quaternion AddRot = Quaternion.identity;
        float roll = 0;
        float pitch = 0;
        float yaw = 0;


        roll = Input.GetAxis("Roll") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed);
        pitch = Input.GetAxis("Pitch") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed);
        yaw = Input.GetAxis("Yaw") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed);
        AddRot.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-pitch, yaw, -roll);
        _rigidBody.rotation *= AddRot;
        Vector3 AddPos = Vector3.forward;
        AddPos = _rigidBody.rotation * AddPos;
        _rigidBody.velocity = AddPos * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * AmbientSpeed);

        if(Vector3.Dot(transform.up, Vector3.down) > 0)
        {
            _rigidBody.AddForce(0, 0, -10);
        }


    }
}
```

Im sorry if i respond late as won't be back on PC till Monday but looking for help with this. Most of the code is from a flight tutorial but the throttle kind of thing in the update() is from me. The script is applied to a rigid-body with box collides .

Comment: What error do you get in the console?  Please post it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of Unity's `Update()`, but if it is executed once per frame, then if an input *is* down, it will always be down whilst processing that frame, and the while loops will prevent you leaving the update, crashing your game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're crashing because you get stuck in an infinite loop when the Update method runs and reaches the first `while` statement:

```
// Wrong
void Update()
{
    while (Input.GetKeyDown("z")) { }
}
```

A `while` statement will loop until the condition becomes `false`. The condition will never become `false` for the specific `Update()` call you clicked `z`.

`Update()` executes once every frame. So if you want to check if someone is holding down "z" in *THIS* frame, you use `if`:

```
// Correct
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("z")) { }
}
```

This will give you the effect that you *intended* to get with `while`:

> while user holds down "z" execute this code".

because the `Update()` will *act* like the loop you're trying to get `while` to achieve.

---

Another thing; by your usage of `while` I assumed that you want something to happen every frame that the `z` key is held down. `GetKeyDown` will only be true for the ONE frame that you clicked it. If you want to check if it is being held down for any number of frames you should use `GetKey`:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z)) {
    // Executes every frame Z is being held down
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses changing it to an if statement fixed it. Again thank you